# Having URL without .aspx extension

Tags: asp.net, url

I noticed a lot of ASP .Net sites does not have the URL ending with ".aspx".

An example would be:
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions

Did they create a Questions folder and put a Default.aspx inside?

In that case, wouldn't there be A LOT of default.aspx in many folders which is hard to maintain (even though it is user-friendly)?

Thanks y'all.

Comment: Thanks all. My coding has greatly improved ever since I've stackoverflow-ed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

StackOverflow is written using ASP.NET MVC. The MVC framework does not use `.aspx` files.

The way it works internally is by using routing tables - see an overview [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/asp-net-mvc-routing-overview-cs).

You can also do this with [ASP.NET](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/11/using-routing-with-webforms.aspx) and `.aspx` files or you can use [URL rewriting](http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite). You can read about the differences [here](http://ruslany.net/2008/09/aspnet-routing-request-filtering-url-rewriting/).

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to any URL rewriter or a routing technique for that. If you look at the new AS{.NET MVC, it works on that model only.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Url Rewriter](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/02/26/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net.aspx)  to remove extensions from the urls of your website.

Answer (score 1):

ASP.net has a routing framework you can use even if you are not using ASP.net MVC

Official documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx

Also as previously stated [ASP.net MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc) works like this out of the box and you can also use [URL Rewriting](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/460/using-the-url-rewrite-module/)

Answer (score 1):

With ASP.NET 4.0, you get the benefits of URL routing (nice, clean URLs) with ASP.NET webforms, too — see:

- [Routing for Web Forms in ASP.NET 4.0](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/01/25/routing-for-web-forms-in-asp.net-4.0.aspx)
- [URL Routing with ASP.NET 4 Web Forms (VS 2010 and .NET 4.0 Series)](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/10/13/url-routing-with-asp-net-4-web-forms-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx)

Basically, what you do is define a route like

```
/question/{id}  or  /question/{title}
```

and you then define what ASPX page this is being routed to. Quite nifty!