# How to use URL Rewrite in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-routing, asp.net-routing

I am trying to use a simple URL rewrite.

I am trying shorten the URL on page load to its simplified version (no file extension). I am not using any query string in my URL.

Here is the current URL:

```
http://localhost:64341/Report/MainPage.aspx
```

When the page loads, I want to see this:

```
http://localhost:64341/Report/MainPage
```

Here is the code that I have in my Global.asax file:

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Code that runs on application startup

        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

    }

    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routeCollection)
    {
        routeCollection.MapPageRoute("RouteForCustomer", " MainPage", "~/ MainPage.aspx");
    }
```

How can I achieve this in the code behind when the page loads?

Comment: This is routing, not rewriting.

Comment: Do you have to achieve this in the code behind or are you happy to set it in the web.config file? You can add a rule in there to remove the .aspx

Comment: well, i don't mind using the webconfig file but having all kind of issues when tried to use it.  it says the rewrite module is not recognized or something like that

Comment: check here for resources on how this can be accomplished:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4117035/having-url-without-aspx-extension

Comment: There's also a [pre-release NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.FriendlyUrls) to do this, which Scott Hanselman [covered last September](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingASPNETFriendlyUrlsCleanerURLsEasierRoutingAndMobileViewsForASPNETWebForms.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Try    `Context.RewritePath("http://localhost:64341/Report/MainPage", true);`

Check this blog
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/02/26/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net.aspx

Comment: You might want to add some Context (no pun intended) to your answer. For example does it matter where this is executed from. A link to the docs wouldn't hurt either.