# I want to see only my URL in the URL line on a browser

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, web

I have developed a WEB site www.panos-oliveoil.gr
When a customer surfing in my web site at the URL line watching the full paths from my site folders.
What can I do; regardless where the customer is surfing; in the URL Line to see a Standard Name. Like my web URL only
I'm developing in VB with VS2010; please in case you want to assist me use this Language

Comment: Sir, are you the owner of the site?

Comment: Sir, I think you are searching for this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4117035/having-url-without-aspx-extension  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45340/friendly-urls-for-asp-net

Comment: @ArabicProgrammer Dear Sir; Nothing helps me from the links that you give me to search. I thik I have give a wrong question. Please let me fix it

Comment: Do you mean you want to have the url stay the same ("www.panos-oliveoil.gr") no matter what page they click to? Or do you simply want cleaner/nicer names than what you get from the directories and filenames?

Comment: As Arabic Programmer implied, it looks like you want to use "URL rewriting". You will also have to make sure that the URLs you render to the client have the form which you want the user to see.

Comment: Could just throw everything in an iframe.

Comment: @Graham your firrst option is what I need... That's exactly I need

Comment: @AndrewMorton I did make what Arabic Programmer told me to do but it didn't work out. Probably because I didn’t make it right due to I'm a beginner in C#

Comment: The `iframe` answer from Kevin is the way to go. And it doesn't really have anything to do with C#, its an HTML thing. Google "html iframe" for examples on how to do it. Having said that, DO NOT DO THIS. You will prohibit your users from being able to bookmark pages, or email links to their friends, etc. It might impact Search Engine placement as well. Just name your pages properly and be done with it.

Comment: @Graham Yes you're most right on this option; I never thought it this way. I'll leave my efforts on this... it is probably not so right to do it. But please apply your answer properly in orderto give you credits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final solution here is that:
What ever I want to do on my WEB site the URL  must be there sowing the details for the place where the surfer is
Most close to this is the answer from Graham.

Answer (score 2):

If you're really trying to have JUST your base url in the navigation bar then you'll have to do some trickery. The url shows for a reason, so you know where you're at. The only way I can think of to trick your browser into only showing the base url is to use iframes. You'd do this like:

```
<iframe src="www.panos-oliveoil.gr"></iframe>
```

Comment: Can you please assist me and give me an advice where to put this controle

Comment: As @Graham said above, it's an html tag. What it does is just display another page from within your page. It is very bad practice to use it to keep your url clean. It's more for smaller sections of an otherwise full page, such as displaying Google maps from within your site. If you tell us what your aim is then we may provide a better solution that will be more user friendly. Otherwise you just throw the iframe tag I have in my answer in a page with the url to your actual content, size it how you want and it's good to go.